# Why does opening Microsoft Edge dev tools reload the current page?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm using Microsoft Edge in Windows 1803, build 17134.376.

I have an ASP.NET Core website running locally in IIS. The website opens up fine in Edge, but when I press `F12` to open the dev tools, all I see is a blank space on the right of the page where the tools are about to appear, but then the entire web page just reloads by itself.

If I press `F12` again, I see an error page with the message:

> This page is having a problem loading
>
> We tried to load this page for you a few times, but there is still a problem with this site. We know you have better things to do than to watch this page reload over and over again so try coming back to this page later.

This behaviour happens on any website I viewe in Edge.

Has anyone here experienced this and can provide a solution please?

EDIT:

Someone has opened an issue report on the MS Edge issues site relating to the problem I'm encountering:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19598526/

Comment: @ jason, Did you try to use the PowerShell command below to solve the issue as mentioned in the link? If not, Than try to make a test with it and let us know about the result. 'Add-AppxPackage -register “C:\windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml” -DisableDevelopmentMode -Confirm:$false'

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Executing that script worked for me, thanks. If you move your comment to an answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try to use the PowerShell command below to solve the issue as mentioned in the link?

If not, Than try to make a test with it and let us know about the result.

> Add-AppxPackage -register
>   “C:\windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml”
>   -DisableDevelopmentMode -Confirm:$false

Comment: Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else stumbles on this issue from a web search, Deepak's answer above worked for me, but the issue resurfaced a few days later and the fix no longer worked. I was able to fix the issue the second time following this comment from a separate bug report:

> Found it again, it was related to an update (kb4462933, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462933/windows-10-update-kb4462933).
>   Solution worked again today, delete the JSByteCodeCache_64 (or JSByteCodeCache_32 for 32 bits systems) in the following folder:
>   C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient_8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata\Autogen
>   The issue should have been resolved with KB4467702, but seems to occur again.

Link to thread: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19457163/

Edit: you may have to perform a search for this file if you have "show hidden files" disabled.

Edit 2: If none of these fixes work there seems to be a connection to webpack dev server, so you might have to look into that. Unfortunately I have not managed to find a solution to that problem.